# DataMapper says TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have an extremely simple table, almost a key/value store, something like

```
class Device
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :token,    Text, :key => true
end
```

and of course I call `DataMapper.finalize` after defining it, because I'm using Sinatra.

When I create a new device, like this

```
Device.create(:token => "Foo Bar")
```

I get all this giant dump

```
~ (0.000063) SET sql_auto_is_null = 0
~ no implicit conversion from nil to integer
TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/quoting.rb:12:in `quote_string'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/quoting.rb:12:in `quote_value'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/command.rb:69:in `block in escape_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/command.rb:62:in `gsub!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/command.rb:62:in `escape_sql'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:114:in `execute_non_query'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in create'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:113:in `block in create'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:85:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:85:in `create'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/repository.rb:146:in `create'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource/persistence_state/transient.rb:74:in `create_resource'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource/persistence_state/transient.rb:25:in `commit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:963:in `_persist'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:977:in `block in create_with_hooks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:974:in `catch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:974:in `create_with_hooks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1028:in `save_self'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:54:in `save_self'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1013:in `block in _save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1229:in `run_once'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1012:in `_save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:412:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:40:in `block in save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations/context.rb:16:in `in_context'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:40:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:130:in `create'
    from (irb):19
    from /usr/bin/irb:12
```

and of course a very similar thing happens when I run the exact same code within Sinatra. I'm running Ruby 2.0, just in case it wasn't clear.

Any clues?

**EDIT**: I have since moved to Rails because of time constraints, but I love Sinatra and I'd still like to make this work, so if anyone had ideas, I still very much welcome them.

Comment: Did you run `DataMapper.auto_migrate!` ? If not run it and let me know.

Comment: I already have a schema in my data store, there's no need to run that, but just for fun I ran it (right after finalize, because where else are you even supposed to run it in a Sinatra application?) and I got almost the exact same dump (save for a few line numbers and the like).

Comment: Weird. It worked perfectly for my DataMapper+Sqlite+Ruby 2.0 setup. `Device.all #=> [#<Device @token="Foo Bar">]`

Comment: @kiddorails, as a matter of fact I can fetch all `Device`s without problems, I just can't seem to make it create new ones.

Comment: @Morpheu5 The above listing(in my output) was created by `Device.create(:token => "Foo Bar")` itself.

Comment: @kiddorails The only difference I can think of is that I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent hours pulling my hair out trying to overcome this exact problem on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty). It seemed completely nonsensical, trying to debug the problem in the data-objects gem was futile.

My solution: Uninstall `libmariadbclient-dev`, install `libmysqlclient-dev`, re-deploy and it finally worked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and was also using Ruby 2.0 (default ruby on OS X Mavericks). Upgrading to 2.1.2 fixed the problem.

If you are actually using OS X I would recommend installing via [RVM](https://rvm.io/) with

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```